# Determining parametric equation given 3 points

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, parametric

Determine parametric equations for the plane through the points $$A(2, 1, 1), B(0, 1, 3), C(1, 3, −2)$$

Comment: What did you try? Hint: a point $M$ is in the plane $(ABC)$ iff the vectors $\overrightarrow{AM}$, $\overrightarrow{AB}$, $\overrightarrow{AC}$ are coplanar, which happens only when their determinant vanishes. For a parametric equation, notice that $A$ is in the plane, and  $\overrightarrow{AB}$, $\overrightarrow{AC}$ are two noncollinear vectors parallel to the plane, thus $M=A+\lambda\overrightarrow{AB}+\mu\overrightarrow{AC}$ is rather obvious.

Comment: make the ansatz $$ax+by+cz+d=0$$

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut I think i know where to go with this now. so            AB = (0-2, 1-1, 3-1) and AC = (1-2, 3-1, -2-1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to solve the system
$$2a+b+c+d=0$$
$$b+3c+d=0$$
$$a+3b-2c+d=0$$
or a parametric form $$[x,y,z]=[2,1,1]+s[-2,0,2]+t[-1,2,-3]$$
or
$$x=2-2s-t$$
$$y=1+2t$$
$$z=1+2s-3t$$

Comment: I got the points AB (-2, 0, 2) and AC (-1,2,-3) but how do i form it into the x, y, and z equations?

Comment: I'm not sure how to get the first number for the equations.                        x= ?-2s-1t         y= ?-0s-3             z= ?+2s+1t

Comment: the equation is $$[x,y,z]=OA+sAB+tAC$$

Comment: Oh okay! So        x= 2-2s-1t               y= 1-0s-3              z= 1+2s+1t    Thank you!